# Determine how long embedded YouTube video was played for after it pauses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube

I have a YouTube video that I'd like to embed on my page and then get how many seconds of the video was played after it is paused. I can do this for an ordinary HTML `video` tag by getting the time of the `play`/`playing`/`ended`/`pause` events, then calculating the time difference between them; I have a demo of this at https://jsfiddle.net/p56a1r45/2/. However I'm not sure how to do the same thing for a YouTube video.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't just post a link to jsfiddle, insert your code (better as SO snippet) instead or besides that. Please also don't put keywords into the text instead of tags (I've fixed that for you and also improved grammar/wording of the question). Please use the "edit" button to improve your question

Comment: @YakovL Eh... while that's normally what we ask of people, it seems relevant the code in this case is incidental to the question, lengthy, and in any case dependent upon further off-site resources to function; I actually think keeping it off-site might be the right thing to do.

Comment: @MarkAmery well, after your edit it's a bit better, but actually I'd say that the provided code is not a minimal code to both reproduce the issue and show how the elapsed time is extracted for an "ordinary" video, so after adding the code here I'd suggest to reduce it to a [mcve]. With your comment (edit) about specific events it's a bit closer to what I consider appropriate for SO, but I'd say the question can (and probably should) be improved further. Whatever, let Sachin decide

Answer (score 0):

First, let's note that Okeksii is correct on 2 points:

1. (almost quoting) Youtube link is not a direct video link. YouTube video is usually located in an iframe. That means you need access to that iframe to get some data or to parse a direct link from YouTube. But for security reasons you can't access YouTube iframe from your website directly.
2. you have to use youtube API instead

and the relevant API is [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). You have to [listen (`player.addEventListener`)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener) to the certain events (presumably [`onStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) is enough: at least it is fired on play and pause), get the current time ([`player.getCurrentTime()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getCurrentTime)) and calculate the elapsed time.

Before that, you have to learn how to [setup the API usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started), though.

Answer (score -1):

[HTML5 Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
How it Works
The controls attribute adds video controls, like play, pause, and volume.

It is a good idea to always include width and height attributes. If height and width are not set, the page might flicker while the video loads.

The <source> element allows you to specify alternative video files which the browser may choose from. **The browser will use the first recognized format.**

The text between the <video> and </video> tags will only be displayed in browsers that do not support the <video> element.
```

As you can see
**The browser will use the first recognized format.**

Youtube link is not a direct video link. Youtube video usually located in a frame. That's means you need access frame to get some data or parse a direct link from youtube.

But for security reasons you can't access youtube iframe from your website as i know

You can try [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) maybe you can find what you're looking for

Comment: -1 because the first link, the quote (which is wrongly formatted as a code block instead of a quote) and the following sentence are all irrelevant. Once you actually start talking about YouTube, it's all at least relevant, but falls short of answering the question; this is really just a couple of pointers.

Comment: actually, you are also pointing to the wrong API. You should elaborate your answer to make it helpful